# Why VS doesn't see included files?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, cmake, cross-platform

I am a student writing a project. I have created a program (here's the link to SVN: https://mysvn.ru/Ilya_Antonov/antonov_sem_prj). I use CMake to build it and generate the .sln project. But when run it in Visual Studio, there are some errors: the compiler can't open the files "drumswindow.h" and "mainwindow.h" (fatal error C1083). Please, take a look at my CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1.0)

project(MusicSimulator VERSION 1.0.0 LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)

if(CMAKE_VERSION VERSION_LESS "3.7.0")
    set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
endif()


find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Gui REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Widgets REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Core REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Multimedia REQUIRED)

add_executable(MusicSimulator
    mainwindow.ui
    mainwindow.cpp
    mainwindow.h
    main.cpp
    drumswindow.ui
    drumswindow.cpp
    drumswindow.h
    keyswindow.ui
    keyswindow.cpp
    keyswindow.h
    images.qrc
    drumres.qrc
    keysres2.qrc
    keysres3.qrc
    keysres4.qrc
    keysres5.qrc
    keysres6.qrc
)

target_link_libraries(MusicSimulator Qt5::Widgets Qt5::Gui Qt5::Core Qt5::Multimedia)
```

What have I done wrong here?

Comment: You probably should have `set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)` enabled regardless of the CMake version.

Comment: `#include <drumswindow.h>` should be `#include "drumswindow.h"` although either will work. The difference I believe is `#include "drumswindow.h"` searches the same  directory as the source file first. however the rules are implementation defined.

Comment: Related to msvc: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/hash-include-directive-c-cpp?view=msvc-160](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/hash-include-directive-c-cpp?view=msvc-160)

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't include the current source dir and therefore the compiler doesn't find it. Either add the current source dir or use the correct include statements (`#include "keyswindow.h"` for example)

Comment: Thank you very much!